# Access separately to each element from a list string

Tags: loops, groovy, iterator

I'm trying to access each element from a string object and concatenate it with another string:

Current output: from object -> **hrsize**

```
4,77GB
1,91GB
2,86GB
```

After converting KB's to GB's I need to give a name to all outputs.
To be like this:

```
TotalMemory: 4,77GB
MemoryAvailable: 1,91GB
MemoryFree: 2,86GB
```

With this output, I will be able to convert this to a Hashmap. (k , v)

I tried to iterate over the list to assign a name to each value but without success.

I will leave the full code:

```
class Example {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        int A = 5000000 //TotalMemory -> Kb
        int B = 2000000 // MemoryAvailable -> Kb
        int C = 3000000 // MemoryFree -> Kb
        
        int[] array = [ A, B, C ] // Convert all variables into an Array

        for(int i in array) {

def size = i // Converting each element from the object to be converted into MB GB or TB

// Memory can be converted in KB MB GB AND TERABYTE depending on its size
String hrSize = ""

try {
    int k = size
    double m = size / 1024 // bytes
    double g = size / 1048576 // bytes
    double t = size / 1073741824 // bytes

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00")

    if (k > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1024 bytes, the output will be KiloBytes
        hrSize = dec.format(k).concat("KB")
    }
    if (m > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1048576 bytes, the output will be Megabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(m).concat("MB")
    }
    if (g > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb and more than 1048576 but less than 1073741824 bytes, the output will be Gigabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(g).concat("GB")
    }
    if (t > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1073741824 bytes the output will be Terabytes.
        hrSize = dec.format(t).concat("TB")
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    println("This program ran into a problem, root cause" + e)

}
 println(hrSize)
        }

    }
}
```

I really hope someone can help me because I'm struggling with this for days now.
Probably this is something pretty basic but I did my best to solve it alone; no joy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a map literal:

```
import java.text.*

Map map = [ TotalMemory:5000000,  //-> Kb
            MemoryAvailable:2000000,  // -> Kb
            MemoryFree:3000000 ] // -> Kb

def toSize = { int size ->
  String hrSize = ""

    int k = size
    int m = size >> 10 // bytes
    int g = size >> 20 // bytes
    int t = size >> 30 // bytes

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00")

    if (k > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1024 bytes, the output will be KiloBytes
        hrSize = dec.format(k).concat("KB")
    }
    if (m > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1048576 bytes, the output will be Megabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(m).concat("MB")
    }
    if (g > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb and more than 1048576 but less than 1073741824 bytes, the output will be Gigabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(g).concat("GB")
    }
    if (t > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1073741824 bytes the output will be Terabytes.
        hrSize = dec.format(t).concat("TB")
    }

  hrSize
}

map.each{ it.value = toSize( it.value ) }

println map
```

prints:

```
[TotalMemory:4.00GB, MemoryAvailable:1953.00MB, MemoryFree:2.00GB]
```

Also you can use some apache-commons-like library to do the size formatting for you, so you don't reinvent the wheel again

Comment: You can also reverse the `if` chain by starting with `if (t > 1)` and using `else if` for subsequent conditions, to avoid redundant checks.